# How to I read a line, modify it slightly and write it back using awk/sed?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a json file of the following format:

```
[
    {
        "organization": "ABC", 
        "type": "School", 
        "contact": "Joe Schmo", 
        "contact_title": "Principal", 
        "mailing_address": "123 Main Street, Anytown, MA", 
        "phone": "214-555-5430",
        "fax": "214-555-5444"
    },
    {
        "organization": "XYZ",
        "type": "School",
        "contact": "John Doe", 
        "contact_title": "Asst Principal", 
        "mailing_address": "123 Main Street, Anycity, TX", 
        "phone": "512-555-5430",
        "fax": "512-555-5444"
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I want to duplicate the line starting with `"organization"` and then add it back to the file twice after replacing `"organization"` with `"company"` and `"long name"`. I want to keep the original line too.
The output I want is:

```
[
    {
        "organization": "ABC",
        "company": "ABC",
        "long name": "ABC", 
        "type": "School", 
        "contact": "Joe Schmo", 
        "contact_title": "Principal", 
        "mailing_address": "123 Main Street, Anytown, MA", 
        "phone": "214-555-5430",
        "fax": "214-555-5444"
    },
    {
        "organization": "XYZ",
        "company": "XYZ",
        "name": "XYZ",
        "type": "School",
        "contact": "John Doe", 
        "contact_title": "Asst Principal", 
        "mailing_address": "123 Main Street, Anycity, TX", 
        "phone": "512-555-5430",
        "fax": "512-555-5444"
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

`awk` or `sed` solutions preferred.

Comment: awk/sed and json in the same sentence ? oO Better use Perl, Python, Ruby and a JSON Parser !

Comment: JSON is an *interchange* format, not a data storage format. Rather than edit it directly, you should use a JSON parser to read it into an appropriate data structure in the language of your choice, make modifications to the *data*, then write the data out in JSON again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
sed '/organization/p;s/organization/company/p;s/company/long name/' file
```

Here is another:

```
awk '$1~/organization/{print $0;sub(/organization/,"company");print $0;sub(/company/,"long name")}1' file
```

Comment: Seems not robust/reliable.

Comment: @sputnick luckily a robust/reliable solution was not asked for.